# Hypothesis Testing in Particle Physics and Invarient Masses Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

I know that  decay might correspond to one of the two following decay chains:

$$ B^{+} \rightarrow f_2^0 \pi^+ , \text{followed by } f_2^0 \rightarrow \pi^+ \pi ^- ;$$
or
$$ B^{+} \rightarrow \rho^0 \pi^+ , \text{followed by } \rho^0 \rightarrow \pi^+ \pi ^- ;$$

where $f_2^0$ and $\rho^0$ are short-lived intermediate particles.

I have been given the momentum components of each of the 3 pion tracks produced from the decays and I need to work out which intermediate particle was present.

I tried to do this using invariant masses with the two final pions produced after the second decay, but this calculation does not produce a mass for the intermediate particle which corresponds to either option. Do I also need to incorporate the momentum of the pion produced from the initial $B^+$ decay?

Any hints would be appreciated! I have the values of the masses and momentum components if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just take the $\pi^+ \pi^-$ pair, add the energies numerically to get the total, add the momenta vectorially to get the total, and calculate $M=\sqrt{(E^2-P^2)}$.

But you have to do this for each of the $\pi^+$ particles with the $\pi^-$. You do not know which came from the $B$ and which from the intermediate meson.

Also your opening statement is potentially misleading. An observed decay is driven by amplitudes, not probabilities, and asking "Was it the $\rho$ or the $f$?" is like asking "Which slit did the photon in Young's slits go through?"  And the decay may match a $\rho$ for one $\pi^+$ AND an $f$ for the other.